# Deleting images from Google Photos without deleting them from the device

Tags: xiaomi, google-photos

I've created a folder in Google Photos with images that were in other folders. I want to delete the images from the other folders without deleting them from the device. But when I delete them, they get deleted from the new folder and the device.

Is it possible to only delete the images from Google Photos without deleting them from the device?

Comment: This reminds me that Google Photos is actually a syncing solution, not a backup solution. Anything that is done with it will be synced to the server and devices.